# How get the average from three different datasets in R

Tags: r, dataset, weather

I've started using R 3 months ago, and working with information from weather stations. Now I want to get the average from three different datasets of the station located in the same place.

My data frames look like this :

d1

| Date_Measure | Id | Tmin | Tmax | Tmedia | Smin | Smax | Smedia | Hrmin | Hrmax | Hrmedia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-21 06:00:00 | M03100245 | 19.10 | 19.97 | 19.335 | 25.04 | 71.14 | 44.930 | 83.78 | 84.28 | 84.280 |
| 2020-06-21 07:00:00 | M03100245 | 20.31 | 21.69 | 20.915 | 89.69 | 144.34 | 108.220 | 81.76 | 83.78 | 82.510 |
| 2020-06-21 08:00:00 | M03100245 | 21.87 | 24.64 | 22.840 | 115.56 | 263.31 | 183.035 | 76.70 | 81.76 | 79.985 |

d2

| Date_Measure | Id | Tmin | Tmax | Tmedia | Smin | Smax | Smedia | Hrmin | Hrmax | Hrmedia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-21 06:00:00 | M03100247 | 19.43 | 20.20 | 19.560 | 17.46 | 68.28 | 37.880 | 91.69 | 92.72 | 92.720 |
| 2020-06-21 07:00:00 | M03100247 | 20.64 | 21.81 | 21.050 | 87.55 | 139.98 | 105.535 | 87.07 | 91.18 | 88.865 |
| 2020-06-21 08:00:00 | M03100247 | 21.85 | 24.75 | 23.015 | 112.42 | 266.65 | 183.440 | 75.24 | 86.55 | 82.695 |

d3

| Date_Measure | Id | Tmin | Tmax | Tmedia | Smin | Smax | Smedia | Hrmin | Hrmax | Hrmedia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-21 06:00:00 | M03100296 | 19.39 | 20.16 | 19.560 | 29.18 | 77.94 | 48.900 | 89.61 | 90.69 | 90.690 |
| 2020-06-21 07:00:00 | M03100296 | 20.55 | 21.53 | 20.805 | 95.95 | 154.43 | 116.065 | 85.82 | 89.07 | 86.370 |
| 2020-06-21 08:00:00 | M03100296 | 21.62 | 24.88 | 23.035 | 122.26 | 280.18 | 194.635 | 71.22 | 85.28 | 79.870 |

I want to take an average of each date and each hour for them in a single general table that combines the three, how can I do this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the 3 dataframes, extract date and hour from `Date_Measure` variable and take average of numeric variables using `across`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

bind_rows(d1, d2, d3) %>%
  #Or instead of writing them individually, we can also use
  #bind_rows(mget(paste0('d', 1:3))) %>%
  mutate(Date_Measure = ymd_hms(Date_Measure), 
         Date = as.Date(Date_Measure),
         Hour = hour(Date_Measure)) %>%
  group_by(Date, Hour) %>%
  summarise(across(Tmin:Hrmedia, mean), .groups = 'drop')

#   Date        Hour  Tmin  Tmax Tmedia  Smin  Smax Smedia Hrmin Hrmax Hrmedia
#  <date>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 2020-06-21     6  19.3  20.1   19.5  23.9  72.5   43.9  88.4  89.2    89.2
#2 2020-06-21     7  20.5  21.7   20.9  91.1 146.   110.   84.9  88.0    85.9
#3 2020-06-21     8  21.8  24.8   23.0 117.  270.   187.   74.4  84.5    80.8
```

Answer (score -2):

First make the number of dataset entries to be the same in all of them.

Then create another dataset by iterating over the column of date and hour.

I guess you need to generate the remaining columns by appropriate formulas.

Comment: Such an answer would usually include the code for the operations described. This generic explanation is a better fit to a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @Abhinav thanks for your help I'm going to try like you mention